# How to set an IP for automatic failover with repmgr can been accessed from application?

Tags: failover

- OS: CentOS
- DB: PostgreSQL

By repmgr, set replication and automatic failover on 2 database servers successfully.

```
 ID | Name  | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string
----+-------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------
 1  | node1 | standby |   running | node2    | default  | 100      | 2        | host=node1 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
 2  | node2 | primary | * running |          | default  | 100      | 2        | host=node2 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr connect_timeout=2
```

The nodes IPs:

- node1: 192.168.0.1
- node2: 192.168.0.2

Set database connection IP with `192.168.0.1`. But when node1 failed, it can't switch to `192.168.0.2` automaticlly. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What platform is this? Meaning, what OS, what DBMS are you using? Details will help us help you.  :)

Comment: @H.79 I have known that `repmgr` can't do that. Need `pgpool`.

Comment: You should tag the platform used for this post. It will help those cruising to potential come into your thread. I'm not a PostgreSQL guy.... If it was MS SQL then I could help you.  :)

Comment: @H.79 Thank you all the same.